# Devise - forgot password - no route matches [GET] "/users/password"

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I just implemented the password reset function via devise but after following the link I receive per email and resetting my password I get the following error:

No route matches [GET] "/users/password" (Routing Error)

I would assume the routing works through devise?

My code in routes.rb looks like this:

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
           sessions: 'users/sessions',
           passwords: 'users/passwords',
           registrations: 'users/registrations'
         }
```

I didn't change anything under controllers > users > passwords_controller.rb but in case it's helpful to see it, it looks like this:

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  # GET /resource/password/new
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource/password
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource/password
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # def after_resetting_password_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sending reset password instructions
  # def after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for(resource_name)
  #   super(resource_name)
  # end
end
```

Am I missing anything or did I do something wrong?

When I add "get 'users/password'" to routes.rb, I get the error:

The action 'password' could not be found for UsersController (Unknown action)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't edit solutions into your question. Instead, post the solution as an answer below. The format on this site is always "Question on top, answers below".

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue and couldn't find any solution.
There can be two reasons for this error

1. there is no rails-ujs (or jquer-ujs) javascript file working on this page
2. no recoverable in User model

But in my case, there was **no problem with these two**, and **password was changed after error page** so I fixed this error by adding line in `routes.rb` as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'users/password', to: redirect("/")
end
```

Comment: This solution work you are right and that fix the issue when user want to reload the page after redirected to users/password ...I will probably build a better logic then but that do the job for now

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have `recoverable` in User model:

```
class User
  devise :database_authenticatable,
         :registerable,
         :validatable,
         :recoverable
end
```

Please let me know if it does not help you.

Comment: Can you please run this command and share the output.
rake routes | grep users/password
And make sure that your password controller must exist in users directory.